# Use basic and jwt authentication in different routes with Adonis JS

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, basic-authentication, adonis.js

I am developing an app with Adonis JS and I have a problem with authentication. I intend to use two authentication schemes for this app: basic and jwt. Set the authenticator field with jwt in the auth.js file

```
'use strict'

module.exports = {
  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Authenticator
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Authentication is a combination of serializer and scheme with extra
  | config to define on how to authenticate a user.
  |
  | Available Schemes - basic, session, jwt, api
  | Available Serializers - lucid, database
  |
  */
  authenticator: 'jwt',

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Session
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Session authenticator makes use of sessions to authenticate a user.
  | Session authentication is always persistent.
  |
  */
  session: {
    serializer: 'lucid',
    model: 'App/Models/User',
    scheme: 'session',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password'
  },

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Basic Auth
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The basic auth authenticator uses basic auth header to authenticate a
  | user.
  |
  | NOTE:
  | This scheme is not persistent and users are supposed to pass
  | login credentials on each request.
  |
  */
  basic: {
    serializer: 'mongoose',
    model: 'App/Models/User',
    token: 'App/Models/Token',
    scheme: 'basic',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password'
  },

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Jwt
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The jwt authenticator works by passing a jwt token on each HTTP request
  | via HTTP `Authorization` header.
  |
  */
  jwt: {
    serializer: 'mongoose',
    model: 'App/Models/User',
    token: 'App/Models/Token',
    scheme: 'jwt',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password',
    options: {
      secret: 'self::app.appKey'
    }
  },

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Api
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | The Api scheme makes use of API personal tokens to authenticate a user.
  |
  */
  api: {
    serializer: 'lucid',
    model: 'App/Models/User',
    scheme: 'api',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password'
  }
}
```

The routes are defined as follows:

```
'use strict'

const Route = use('Route')

Route.post('/login', 'UserController.login').middleware('auth:basic')
Route.post('/register', 'UserController.register')
// Route.post('/logout', 'UserController.logout').middleware('auth')
Route.get('/users/me', 'UserController.me').middleware('auth')
```

As you can see, the /login uses basic authentication and the /me uses jwt

The controller is this:

```
'use strict'

const User = use('App/Models/User')
const Logger = use('Logger')

class UserController {

  async login({ request, auth, response }) {
    const { email, password } = await auth.getUser()
    Logger.info(email, password)
    const { token } = await auth.attempt(email, password)
    response.status(200).send({ token })
  }

  async register({ request, auth, response }) {
    const { email, password, fullName } = request.post()
    const user = await User.create({ email, password, fullName })
    response.status(201).send('ok')
  }

  async me({ request, auth, response }) {
    response.status(200).send(auth.user)
  }

}

module.exports = UserController
```

When I do the test with Postman I get this error:

[image: Error in Postman]

Apparently even though the basic authentication works, when I try to get the user of the auth object, it tells me that there is no jwt.
As I can solve this problem, the intention is that with the login to generate the jwt for the other routes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass "guest" in middleware to verify if the user is not authenticated

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_guest_middleware